# How to hibernate PC at certain time via Terminal?

Tags: command-line, sudo, hibernate, time

Are there any commands via Terminal such as

`sudo shutdown -P 60`

or something like this, but with the role of making the PC hibernate instead of shunting down?

Answer (score 1):

Use `sleep` or `at`:

```
sleep 60; pm-hibernate

at now + 1 minute <<<pm-hibernate
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use sudo:

```
sleep time; dbus-send --system --print-reply \
    --dest="org.freedesktop.UPower" \
    /org/freedesktop/UPower \
    org.freedesktop.UPower.Hibernate
```

*time is in seconds.